# Configure postfix to send via IPV4 but receive using both IPV4 & IPV6?

Tags: postfix, smtp, ipv6

Is it possible to configure postfix to send via IPV4 only but receive using both IPV4 & IPV6?

My server, running on AWS Lightsail, now can have an IPV6 address. The address is relatively static (as long as I keep IPV6 active on the instance), but it's not truly static because I can't move the address from server to server (like I can do with the static IPV4 address).  I also can't (currently) as Amazon to assign an PTR record for the IPV6 address.

As I have the IPV6 address available, I'd like to be able to receive mail using either IPV4 or IPV6 but only send using IPV4.

I know I can set postfix to only listen on the IPV4 address using the inet_protocols setting.

Comment: Huh? The `inet_protocols` is absolutely supposed to affect outgoing connections, too. Applying it to your `smtp` service in `master.cf` *should* limit name lookups and connections postfix makes, if that is not the case you are using an old or buggy version.

Comment: Please elaborate ... is there a way to specify inet_protocols only for outgoing connections?  The inet_protocols setting in main.cf appears to control all of postfix.

Comment: You can setup different configuration for `smtpd` (receiving mails) and for `smtp` (sending mails). Define per-service options, e.g. by adding space-prefixed ` -o option=value` after the relevant service in your `master.cf` file.

Answer (score 7):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but you can make postfix prefer IPv4 for outgoing email with this configuration:

```
smtp_address_preference=ipv4
```

That should usually have the effect you desire, unless the receiver explicitly gives the preferred MX only an IPv6 address.

The manual reference: https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_address_preference

Comment: I don't want postfix to use IPV6 to send to any server at all. Only IPV4. I have a static IP address for IPV4 and a PTR record. I don't have the same for the IPV6 address.  I just want to have postfix RECEIVE mail for both IPV6 & IPV4.

Comment: @DavidG I think this is the best you are going to get. I also don't think there are any IPv6-only mail servers out there yet, so it should not be an issue, at least long enough for Amazon to finish joining us in the 21st century.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right.  Thanks.