# postfix: how to force IPv4 through SMTP?

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, ipv6, spf

## Problem

I have successfully set up a Postfix mailserver with an SMTP interface, set up DKIM, DMARC, SPF, all that stuff.

But I had a problem when testing the delivery of emails to Gmail.

Namely, SPF would pass if I sent it by the `sendmail` command from the server (some of the `ARC-Authentication-Results` header content of the delivered message in Gmail):

```
spf=pass (google.com: domain of redacted@example.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=redacted@example.com;
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is an IPv4 address of the server

but would fail if I connected to the server using SMTP and sent it that way with:

```
spf=fail (google.com: domain of redacted@example.com does not designate yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=redacted@example.com;
```

where `yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy` is an IPv6 address of the server.

## Fix

I realized that the SPF DNS record is only set up for the IPv4 address so I set it up that it also works with the IPv6 and it started passing as

```
spf=pass (google.com: domain of redacted@example.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=redacted@example.com;
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the **IPv4** address of the server (weird)

## Questions

1. Is there a way to force IPv4 when sending through the SMTP? Most machines nowadays should handle IPv6 but I would be happier if it didn't touch the IPv6 when I don't want to.
2. How is it possible that before it failed due to IPv6 not being present in the SPF DNS record but now it passes with IPv4 after I added IPv6?

If there are any settings needed to be known, let me know. There are many lines of config files so it wouldn't be practical to post them all.

Comment: You can prefer IPv4 https://serverfault.com/q/1049845/546643 over IPv6

Comment: You should probably fix your IPv6 instead, ensure your PTR, SPF and DKIM is correct and you should mostly be good.

Comment: This is probably why it came through IPv6: *"With Postfix 2.8 the default is "ipv6"; earlier implementations are hard-coded to prefer IPv6 over IPv4."* source: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_address_preference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is as simple as `postconf -e "inet_protocols = ipv4"`

but nothing prevents you from fixing your DNS/SPF over ipv6 as it is said in comment.